# Splitting array into about equals sums without rearranging

Tags: c#, arrays, split, sum, equals

so i have this assignment that has me stumped, i am giving an array of integers for example 
210,50,200,100 (can be any amount or any number) and i need to split it into N parts so the sums would be about equal basically with the smallest difference without sorting or rearranging the numbers,

Example, 210,50,200,300 N = 3; it supposed to split into 210 250 300 (difference between smallest and largest is 90)

I tried a program which takes an average 760/3 ~= 253 and tries to add the number so it takes 210 and looks would adding 50 bring it closer or farther from average so it add's the 50 rinse and repeat so it gets 260 200 300 it's almost good but the difference between 200 and 300 is = 100 so it's not optimal since when calculating without program you can get a better result 210 and 300 only has difference of 90.

**TL:DR
Need a method that splits int array into about equal parts doesn't have to be the same just as close to each other as possible without changing the positions or array.**

If you don't want to give me the method just give me the pseudo code or the basic idea since i been sitting on this for hours.

```
        static int[] Skaiciuoti(int[] knygos, int d)
{
    int[] skyriai = new int[d];
    int n = knygos.Length;
    double sum = knygos.Sum() / d;
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
    int kp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {

        for (int j = kp; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i == skyriai.Length - 1)
            {
                skyriai[i] = skyriai[i] + knygos[j];
                kp++;
            }
            else if ((skyriai[i] + knygos[j]) < sum || skyriai[i] == 0)
            {
                skyriai[i] = skyriai[i] + knygos[j];
                kp++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    return skyriai;

}
```

this is what i tried before.

Comment: This is a basic backtracking algorithm that assigns a group to each number and checks if it's "valid" according to whatever rules are needed.

Comment: You will probably not get an answer until you write some code and paste it into your question (that's how this site works).  Getting the average is a good start.  Off the top of my head, you may also want to calculate the minimum and maximum number of integers you can have in each group.

Comment: What do you mean by *"without changing the positions or array"*? What *exactly* is the expected output?

Comment: @RufusL By that i mean without changing the positions literally if the array is 250 210 230 etc it has to say the same. As for expected outcome i would say imagine it like this:
You have N number of books each with diffirent amount of pages and D number of workers. You have to split the books among the workers so that each worker gets about the same amount of pages as the others. And the outcome would be how many pages each of the workers got to read(Sums);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, which is similar to the code you've already tried. The idea is:

1. Determine the 
   "ideal value" by dividing the sum of the items by the number of parts (`resultCount`) we want to split them into
2. Create a `result` array with `resultCount` indexes
3. Create a `resultIndex` counter to keep track of which index in our `result` array we will add the current `item` to
4. In a `foreach` loop, walk though the array, adding each item to either the current index in the `result` array, or, if that would push us over the `idealValue`, increment our index first.

For example:

```
public static int[] Split(int[] input, int resultCount)
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
    if (resultCount > input.Length || resultCount < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(resultCount));

    var idealValue = input.Sum() / resultCount;
    var result = new int[resultCount];
    var resultIndex = 0;

    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        // Move to the next index in our result array if the
        // next sum puts us over our expected average amount
        if (result[resultIndex] > 0 &&
            result[resultIndex] + item > idealValue &&
            resultIndex < result.Length - 1)
            resultIndex++;

        result[resultIndex] += item;
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

The problem with this is that, if all the items are larger than our "ideal value", then the last index in our `result` array will be far too big, since everything gets pushed there. To solve this issue, we'd probably need to walk through the array twice, first to find out what the value of each item is, and the second time to populate the result with the ideal sums.

Consider the input:

```
new [] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10 }, 3  // Split the array into 3 parts
```

In the sample above, `sum / parts = 18`, so `idealValue = 6`, but in reality we'd end up with a result that looked like: `{ 6, 2, 10 }` instead of `{ 4, 4, 10 }`, which is more evenly spread out.

One way to help solve this is to remove the "outliers" (those items whose value is greater than the ideal) and then re-calculate a new "ideal" value. This gets us a little closer to perfect:

```
public static int[] Split(int[] input, int resultCount)
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
    if (resultCount > input.Length || resultCount < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(resultCount));

    var idealValue = input.Sum() / resultCount;
    var result = new int[resultCount];
    var resultIndex = 0;

    // Recalculate idealValue by removing items over the ideal
    var itemsUnder = input.Where(item => item <= idealValue).ToList();
    idealValue = itemsUnder.Sum() / (resultCount - (input.Length - itemsUnder.Count));

    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        // Move to the next index in our result array if the
        // next sum puts us over our expected average amount
        if (result[resultIndex] > 0 &&
            result[resultIndex] + item > idealValue &&
            resultIndex < result.Length - 1)
            resultIndex++;

        result[resultIndex] += item;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now with the input:

```
new [] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10 }, 3  // Split the array into 3 parts
```

We first calculate the `idealValue = 6`, then we ignore the `10` and take the rest and divide by `(3 - 1)`, for a *new* `idealValue = 4`, and we end up with a result that looks like `{ 4, 4, 10 }`, which is more evenly spread out.

---

This still doesn't help with situations where we end up with a lot of smaller numbers that get summed into the last index (since there's nowhere else to put them).

For example, if we have an input like `{80, 99, 60, 200, 50, 70, 90}`, we will first calculate an `idealValue = 216` (and since none of the items are *over* that amount, it doesn't change in the second re-calculation). But then when we run it though our first iteration, we end up with the result set: `{179, 60, 410}`. Notice that all the smaller values near the end were dumped in the last position.

One way to handle *that* issue is to recalculate the `idealValue` *again* after we generate our first result set. We only want to do this if the results need to be recalculated by checking if the items that are smaller than the `idealValue` have a large enough difference between them that we can fix:

```
public static int[] Split(int[] input, int resultCount)
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
    if (resultCount > input.Length || resultCount < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(resultCount));

    var idealValue = input.Sum() / resultCount;
    var result = new int[resultCount];
    var resultIndex = 0;

    // Recalculate idealValue by removing items over the ideal
    var itemsUnder = input.Where(item => item <= idealValue).ToList();
    idealValue = itemsUnder.Sum() / (resultCount - (input.Length - itemsUnder.Count));

    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        // Move to the next index in our result array if the
        // next sum puts us over our expected average amount
        if (result[resultIndex] > 0 &&
            result[resultIndex] + item > idealValue &&
            resultIndex < result.Length - 1)
            resultIndex++;

        result[resultIndex] += item;
    }

    // Try to determine if the calculated results can be averaged better 
    var resultsOver = result.Where(item => item > idealValue).ToList();
    var resultsUnder = result.Except(resultsOver).ToList();
    if (resultsUnder.Max() - resultsUnder.Min() > resultsUnder.Count)
    {
        // Recalculate idealValue again based on the final results
        // by getting the sum of the difference of the items that are over
        // and dividing it by the total number of items
        idealValue += resultsOver.Select(item => item - idealValue).Sum() / result.Length;

        // Reset our results
        result = new int[resultCount];
        resultIndex = 0;

        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            // Move to the next index in our result array if the
            // next sum puts us over our expected average amount
            if (result[resultIndex] > 0 &&
                result[resultIndex] + item > idealValue &&
                resultIndex < result.Length - 1)
                resultIndex++;

            result[resultIndex] += item;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

So now when we use the input `{80, 99, 60, 200, 50, 70, 90}`, after we calculate the first result set (`{179, 60, 410}`), we re-calculate the `idealValue` by taking the amount that the items are over, getting the average, and adding it to our `idealValue`, like: `410 - 216 = 194, 194 / 3 = 64, idealValue = 216 + 64 = 280`. And then we reset the results and run it again, ending up with:

```
{239, 250, 160}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i did before, and yeah the issue that you described occurred if i took for example numbers: 
80,99,60,200,50,70,90 it would get result 179,60,410 which is far from optimal the code that i posted before works exactly the same as this that you given me.

Comment: I see that you are still editing i get the problem and i already encountered it myself so i completely scratched this method and tried alternative. But from what you are saying you have a solution to this problem would you mind explaining me it in more detail ?

Comment: Yeah, I was coming up with it "on the fly" :). I posted a sample where we re-calculate the "ideal value" by ignoring items that are greater than the actual "ideal", which helps even out the "lows".

Comment: With your improvement when using the sequence 80,99,60,200,50,70,90 split into 3 i get the same wrong results 179,60,410 how do i fix this ?

Comment: If you could give me and example that works with the above sequence that would be amazing.

Comment: I came up with something. It still feels like we're hacking away at it, and there are probably other inputs that will produce bad results, but keep at it and you'll end up with a decent formula. :)

Comment: Thanks that gave me a lot of ideas actually i kinda didn't even think of recalculating with this new found knowledge i will one way or another find a solution. Thanks for your time and info.